# How to reference sibling view controllers from a storyboard

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to create a master-detail app for OSX using view controllers and storyboards.  I have two sibling view controllers (`left` and `right`) with a parent split view controller.

The `left` child is a table vc and has an NSArrayController for its bindings.  I want the user to choose one of the table view cells, and have the `right` child view controller show details about the selection (kind of like the Mail app interface).

The part i'm stuck at is how to reference the `left` view controller from the `right`?  I want to grab `left`'s NSArrayController, so that `right` can bind to the current selection.

I have tried adding an Outlet to `right` and making the connection via Interface Builder, but it seems like IB won't let you drag connections across scenes. I then went looking for a programatic solution. I assumed NSStoryboard would have API to look up a view controller based on some id, but there isn't much API exposed.

I ended up with a sloppy solution of going through the parent view controller, and searching its children to find `left` in `right`'s awakeFromNib.

So is there a more elegant way to connect view controllers when using Storyboards? Thanks for the help.

Comment: With storyboards you generally would use `"segues"` to pass things between `"scenes"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct and only way to do this is to go through a central controller. You've answered your own question essentially - there is no elegant way of automatically discovering the left and right view controllers.